# 'showSnackBar' is deprecated and shouldn't be used

Tags: flutter

Trying to figure out this flutter problem.  The below code has the showSnackbar as deprecated, and am trying to figure out with the fix is.  The second code is my attempt to fix the problem.  A new problem comes up with "The getter 'ScaffoldMessenger' isn't defined for the type 'ScaffoldState'.".  The error tells me to import material.dart file but it is already imported.

Any help is appreciated.

```
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: ()async{
                    if(!await authProvider.signIn()){
                      _key.currentState.showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(content: Text("Login failed"))
                      );
                    }
                  },

              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: ()async{
                    if(!await authProvider.signIn()){
                      _key.currentState.ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(content: Text("Login failed"))
                      );
                    }
                  },
```

Answer (score 99):

Based on the [documentation here](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger), it looks like the new ScaffoldMessenger handles all SnackBars below it. If you don't have multiple ScaffoldMessengers, you should just be able to call:

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Login failed")));
```

Comment: Hi Joe, that is exactly what I have with the error message.

Comment: Have you tried without referenceing _key.currentState before it? I'd try just with the ScaffoldMessenger

Comment: worked for me too thanks. is that means no more need for globalKey<ScaffoldState>, am I right?

Answer (score 20):

This is the new way to add snackBars to the scaffold.

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar( SnackBar( content: Text("Incremented"), duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), ), );
```

Using   `_key.currentState.ShowSnackBar(snackbar)` Is deprecated now.

Answer (score 14):

According to the official documentation:

> 'showSnackBar' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use
> ScaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar. This feature was deprecated after
> v1.23.0-14.0.pre..

New Way of displaying a snackbar:

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Enter somethong here to display on snackbar")));
```

Old Method (using scaffold key):

```
_scaffoldkey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackbar);
```

This no longer can be used, avoid it and use the new way instead.

Answer (score 2):

A simple answer to this is to create a global key in your stateful widget class Like so

```
...
final globalScaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();
...
```

add the variable to your Scaffold

```
...
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        key: globalScaffoldKey,
...
```

and you can access it like

```
...
globalScaffoldKey.currentState!.showSnackBar();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `GlobalKey` of type `ScaffoldMessengerState`

Create a key and assign it to the MaterialApp

```
final scaffoldMessengerKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();

MaterialApp(
  scaffoldMessengerKey: scaffoldMessengerKey,
  child: ...
)
```

Displaying a Snackbar

```
scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState!.showSnackBar(
   SnackBar(content: Text("File Uploaded"))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes `showSnackBar` is deprecated seens `2.0.0` Stable Flutter SDK relese

You can use `ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)` widget to meke it work

**Eg.**

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(scaffoldState.currentContext)
   ..removeCurrentSnackBar()
   ..showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(value),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
     ),
   );
```