# Flutter - 'showSnackBar' is deprecated - how to update?

Tags: flutter, updates, snackbar

I have some outdated parts in my main.dart, i would like to update them, but need a little help because my knowledge is apparently insufficient, hope someone can help me :-)

in this part the snack bar is out of date, as you can see in the message.

> 'showSnackBar' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use
> ScaffoldMessenger.showSnackBar. This feature was deprecated after
> v1.23.0-14.0.pre..

This is the associated code of my main.dart

```
  Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop('dialog');
  Magazin.scaffoldKey.currentState!.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    content: Text('BEIM LADEN DER POST-DATEN IST EIN FEHLER AUFGETRETEN!'),
    duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
  ));
```

I found this therad here in the forum but it didn't really help me ...
['showSnackBar' is deprecated and shouldn't be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65906662/showsnackbar-is-deprecated-and-shouldnt-be-used)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use this code .if rest of your code work currently this code doesn't have any problem

```dart
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop('dialog');
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
     SnackBar(
          content:Text('BEIM LADEN DER POST-DATEN IST EIN FEHLER AUFGETRETEN!'),
          duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, it wasnt obvious that you needed wrap your old Scaffold(...) with a ScaffordMessager(...). As soon as I did this, migration was easy with the above.

New over-ridden build:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScaffoldMessenger(
      key: scaffoldMessengerKey,
      child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
```

Old snippet:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
```

Hope this helps the next person!

Answer (score 1):

**instead of line**

```
   Magazin.scaffoldKey.currentState!.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
```

**but this line**

```
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with Flutter 2 or higher, you might see a deprecation warning regarding the hideCurrentSnackBar() and showSnackbar() methods.

You can get rid of them by using:

ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar()
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackbar(...)
instead of

Scaffold.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar()
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackbar(...)

Answer (score -1):

you can use Flushbar for this features in your app:  [flushbar](https://pub.dev/packages/another_flushbar)

```
FlushbarHelper.createError(
       message: failure.map(
              cancelledByUser: (_) => 'Cancelled',
              serverError: (_) => 'Server error',
              emailAlreadyInUse: (_) => 'Email already in use',
              invalidEmailAndPasswordCombination: (_) =>
                  'Invalid email and password combination',
            ),
          ).show(context);
```