# 'showSnackBar' & 'hideCurrentSnackBar' is deprecated and shouldn't be used

Tags: flutter, dart, deprecated

Please help me out, _scaffoldKey and _scaffoldKey.currentState cuasing main problem while fixing the code.

I have following code:

```
void customSnackBar(GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey, String msg,
    {double height = 30, Color backgroundColor = Colors.black}) {
  if (_scaffoldKey == null || _scaffoldKey.currentState == null) {
    return;
  }
  _scaffoldKey.currentState.hideCurrentSnackBar();
  final snackBar = SnackBar(
    backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
    content: Text(
      msg,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
  );
  _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
}
```

I have gone through `ScaffoldMessenger` documentation but not able to understand how to convert above code to use `ScaffoldMessenger`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['showSnackBar' is deprecated and shouldn't be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65906662/showsnackbar-is-deprecated-and-shouldnt-be-used)

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, you can now use ScaffoldMessenger instead.
take a look here https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/scaffold-messenger
Show it here :

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    content: const Text('snack'),
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
    action: SnackBarAction(
      label: 'ACTION',
      onPressed: () {
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar;
      },
    ),
  ));
```

Comment: Please consider to close this if you already solve this issues. Or mark my question if that's answer your difficulties, so the other can know

Answer (score 3):

Change `GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>` to `GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>`.

Answer (score 2):

use GlobalKey instead of GlobalKey.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).