# How to fix Scaffold Issue

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
void show() {
    scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
      ),
      backgroundColor: haserror ? errorColor : succses,
      behavior: isfloating ? SnackBarBehavior.floating : SnackBarBehavior.fixed,
      margin: isfloating ? EdgeInsets.all(20) : null,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
      action: actionTile != ""
          ? SnackBarAction(
              label: actionTile,
              onPressed: onPressed == null
                  ? () {
                      scaffoldKey.currentState.hideCurrentSnackBar();
                    }
```

i am trying to run some project but have this error

```
    "message": "The method 'showSnackBar' isn't defined for the type 'ScaffoldState'.\nTry correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'showSnackBar'.",
}]
```

i am still confuse how to solve and still new in flutter development

Comment: Are you using null-safety ?

Comment: yes they are using null

Comment: Can you include how you've define `scaffoldKey`

Comment: i am trying make widget with template reference but seem they are not going well in scaffold one

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['showSnackBar' is deprecated and shouldn't be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65906662/showsnackbar-is-deprecated-and-shouldnt-be-used)

Comment: wait let me edit

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of Flutter, you have to use `ScaffoldMessenger` to display a snackbar. Hence, you don't need to store the `scaffoldKey`.

If you are using a `StatefulWidget`, try this:

```
void show() {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(...),
  );
}
```

If you are using a `StatelessWidget`, you need to pass the `context` to the `show` method while calling. Try this in this case:

```
void show(BuildContext context) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(...),
  );
}
```

For hiding the snackbar:

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
```