# Error: The method 'showSnackBar' isn't defined for the class 'ScaffoldState'

Tags: flutter, sdk

`lib/auth/login.dart:49:40: Error: The method 'showSnackBar' isn't defined for the class 'ScaffoldState'.

- 'ScaffoldState' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart' ('../../flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'showSnackBar'.
  return _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^`

`if (response.statusCode == 401) { setState(() => isLoading = false); return _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar( content: Row( mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [ Container(child: Icon(Icons.error)), Text('Invalid username or password'), ], ), action: SnackBarAction( label: 'UNDO', onPressed: () {}, ), )); } }`

Comment: I suspect old code that does not respect the breaking change.  This posting covers that better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65906662/showsnackbar-is-deprecated-and-shouldnt-be-used

Answer (score 0):

To show a `SnackBar`, look up a `ScaffoldMessenger` from the ancestor of the widget tree (more precisely, the element tree). For example:

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

You can read more about it, and example code, from the official docs: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/snackbars